# What is the upper bound of function f(n) = n in Big-O notation and why?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I was reading the book Algorithm by Karumanchi .In one of the example it is given that for function f(n)= n the big-o notation is O(n^2).But why is that and why isn't it O(n) with c=2 and n0=1.

Comment: Look at the definition of big-O. They're not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the theory of computation, not programming. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

f(n) = O(g(n)) sets an upper limit to the function f(n). But this upper limit need not be tight.
So for the function f(n) = n, we can say f(n) = O(n),
also f(n) = O(n^2), f(n) = (n^3) and so on. The definition of Big-Oh doesn't say anything about the tighness of the bound.

Comment: Typically, you want to give a bound `f(n) = O(g(n))` such that `f(n) = o(g(n))` is not also true. For example, `f(n) = o(n^2)` is true, but `f(n) = o(n)` is not.

Comment: This answer is horribly weak. Of course the tightness of the bound matters. And the definition in the Karumanchi book explicitly states that big-O "gives the tight upper bound". So whose definition are you using, and why should Karumanchi have paid more attention to it than the definition he gives on the page preceding the OP's example?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first be sure we understand what Karumanchi was saying. First, on page 61, he states that big-O notation "gives the *tight* upper bound of the given function." (his emphasis). So if O(n) is correct, then O(n^2) is incorrect by his definition.

Then, on page 62, we get the example you cite. He justifies O(n^2) by stating that n <= n^2 for all n >= 1. This is true.

But it is also true that n <= 2n for all n >= 1. (OP's constants.) That justifies the statement n = O(n) with c = 2 and n0 = 1.

So why did he say it's O(n^2)? Who knows? The book is wrong.

Comment: for f(n)=n both statements f(n)=O(n) and f(n)=O(n^2) are correct. Of course O(n) is a much stronger statement and if it can be proved it would typically be stated.

Comment: Quite right, @Henry, but inconsistent with his definitions. The book needs to be interpreted first with respect to itself.